# Identify specs of this filter coil and enable independent use of PSUs fed through it?

Tags: filter, power-electronics, coil, passive-filter

Shown in the pictures is a power supply and distribution system from an old Fuji Xerox all-in-one copier/printer/binder/etc.

In the image that shows multiple components you will see the components laid out with red arrows indicating the connection path from mains in to the 3.5v and 5.5v PSUs. All black and white wires are AC.

Note: The 24.5v PSU and the Filter Board are NOT fed through the Filter Coil. ( I have traced the circuits.) Only the 3 lower-voltage PSUs are fed by it.

Those 3.5 and 5.5v PSUs are *each* 8A output supplies. Fittingly, the Filter Coil has very heavy gauge copper as its winding, and has these markings on the top:

- "104E94220" and TAM 4KO3K"
- I am interpreting the O as an "oh" not a
  zero based on comparison of zero in top line with O in bottom
  line (see picture).

Googling the part numbers of the coil has been no use. Proprietary/custom part.

So, to my question(s):

Can I test to determine the properties of this coil, and how do I do that?

Can I divide that/those specs into thirds to determine what coil would suit each of the three PSUs that were fed through it? (To create standalone power supplies.)

Alternately, just good advice on what filter coil to purchase to place in front of these PSUs would do, though improving my understanding is always better.

EDIT:

Added a screen cap of the circuit from the engineering handbook for the original device. The coil is circled in red. The machine was on 230V mains before deconstruction, which by the diagram means there should be a *resistor* there? Gotta admit I'm very confused by that. A coil is a resistor? Can't be can it?

ALSO- The picture of all the components has the Mains straight to the board, but it actually goes through the Filter Block before going to the distribution board. Anyway, hope the new info helps.

[image: all components]
[image: the coil]
[image: Circuit diagram]
[image: Dist Board]

Comment: How do you know if the mains are wired through the coil? Did you reverse engineer the distribution board? Are you sure that coil is not for PFC? Are you sure those separate supply modules don't work when directly powered from mains? Do the separate modules have any markings about input voltages or part numbers? They look awfully lot like standard mains input power supplies.

Comment: I physically traced the circuit from the plug end to the 3.5/5.5 PSUs. I cannot say what that coil does with any certainty, though use a filter or choke seemed to make sense to me based on where it is in the circuit - but I'm really basic with this stuff so can easily be wrong. The 3.5/5.5 PSUs have markings with specs that include "Input: 220-240VAC". I have been working under the assumption that if there was a coil there before separating them, I should have a coil there after separating them.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the three PSUs WILL work if I connect them directly to mains, but am quite UNcertain about if doing so will be 'good for' them (long term damage?) or if doing so will introduce 'bad' noise in them that would make the supplied DC a problem for other stuff USING the DC.

Comment: My vote is for passive PFC coil.

Comment: Winny - please have a look at the new image I posted of the circuit and advise further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the modules say they are standard power supply modules that can be directly fed with 230VAC mains. The choke might just be to limit inrush current as there are multiple power supplies in parallel. If you are worried about mains filtering then put a mains input filter module there. if you experience bad noise on DC output, it won't be removed by input filter as these are switching mode power supplies.

The inductance and resistance of the original filter coil can be measured with LCR meter, but there is no way to figure out the surge and operating current rating. Only hope to know them is by finding the AC input surge and operating currents of the power supply modules and add them up. But the power supply modules already seem to have proper mains filtering and NTC surge limiting so unless you intend to power all of them with a single mains switch or plug you don't need extra surge filtering.

Comment: Justme - I just posted more info in the question - new diagram - and let me know if this supports your above view or requires changing it? Also, will need direct answers to the questions asked if that's possible?

Comment: @111936 New info completely supports my view. Which question in particular you need answered, as I did not answer the questions about coil measuring and replacement because you don't need a coil to begin with when supplies are used separately so this is an X-Y problem. The coil can be thought as a resistor here as in an AC circuitry they both limit current. It does not limit the normal operating current but the fuse-blowing inrush current of all three modules combined when power switch is flipped.

Comment: A direct answer about measuring the coil, and a direct answer about dividing those values by three to get values to use as independent coils for independent supplies. All the other info is MORE than great to get, but I still want to know about the questions.

Comment: @111936 Well I added what can and what can't be measured from the coil.